# How to create a random index in Jolie

Tags: jolie

I am starting to play around with Jolie I was looking for a way to randomise an index
What include do I need to use, can you create a random integer number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question and interest in Jolie.

1. Can you create a random integer number?
   Not directly
2. What include do I need to use?
   math.iol

Here my simple code

```
include "math.iol"
include "console.iol"

main{
      random@Math()(randomResult);
      randomIndex= int (randomResult*10); // 10 is the maximum index size
      println@Console(randomIndex)()
 }
```

I hope this helps
B